# NSPredicate created within subclass of NSManagedObject crashes

Tags: objective-c, macos, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

When I create a predicate like this, from outside a subclass of NSManagedObject, it works just fine:

```
CNSTag *aTag = ...
_predicateForMatchingObjects = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags == %@", aTag];
```

However, when I try to provide a function for my class CNSTag, as below, the program crashes while trying to create the predicate:

```
- (NSPredicate *)predicateForMatchingObjects {

_predicateForMatchingObjects = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags == %@", self];
return _predicateForMatchingObjects;
}
```

If I access key paths of self in the predicate (e.g., "ANY tags.name == %@", self.name), it works fine; I just can't access self.  Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: 1) Do you have any error message? Does it crash when the predicate is created, or when it is used? - 2) Where is `_predicateForMatchingObjects` declared?

Comment: And are you using ARC or not (ARC turned off will indeed explain the crash, and the exception you got would tell you all about it)

Comment: it's crashing when it's created, and i'm using ARC.  I can't tell what exactly is causing the crash:  it hangs up pretty badly and then puts me into the assembly language.  It doesn't matter where the variable is declared:  it can be declared right there or in the class implementation.  It also doesn't matter how the predicate is created:  i get the same problem if the predicate is created from NSExpressions.  Creating an expression with self doesn't cause the crash;  but creating the predicate from the expressions does.

Comment: I still don't know what the problem is, but I fixed it.  The function in which the predicate was created was defined in a getter for a transient attribute of the NSManagedObject subclass.  I deleted that attribute from the model, and am now just treating it as conventional, unmodeled property of the NSManagedObject subclass.  Everything now works as expected.